# Join 2 tables with counts including rows that don't match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `BANDS` and `SONGS`, and I want to list all bands that recorded less than 3 songs, including those who didn't record any songs, along with a count of the number of songs.

Right now I have this code which prints `IDs` next to number of songs. How can I join those `IDs` to the `BANDS` table and print band names instead of `IDs`?

Also how to show the bands who didn't record any song?

```
    select ID as NAME, count(*) as NUMBER_OF_SONGS from SONGS
    group by ID
    having count(*) < 3;
```

Comment: BANDS have ID and NAME, SONGS have ID which is actually a reference to id of a band which created this song

Comment: so `Songs.Id` actually refers to `Bands.Id`? If so, consider renaming the columns to make that clearer.

Comment: Yes it does, I simplified my database in this example to make my problem easier to understand but now I see it can actually be confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete and hopefully more useful answer for you, which illustrates sample data along with the results it produces. Please run the below sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #band
    (
        BandId INT ,
        BandName NVARCHAR(10)
    );

CREATE TABLE #song
    (
        SongId INT ,
        BandId INT ,
        SongName NVARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT INTO #band ( BandId ,
                    BandName )
VALUES ( 1, 'Rockers' ) ,
       ( 2, 'Rappers' ) ,
       ( 3, 'Ravers' ) ,
       ( 4, 'Poppers' );

INSERT INTO #song ( SongId ,
                    BandId ,
                    SongName )
VALUES ( 1, 1, 'rock 1' ) ,
       ( 2, 1, 'rock 2' ) ,
       ( 3, 1, 'rock 3' ) , -- rock = 3 songs - not output
       ( 4, 2, 'rap 1' ) , 
       ( 5, 2, 'rap 2' ) ,  -- rap = 2 songs - is output
       ( 6, 3, 'rave 1' );  -- rave = 1 song - is output
        -- pop = 0 songs - is output

SELECT   b.BandId ,
         b.BandName ,
         COUNT(s.SongId) Songs
FROM     #band AS b
         LEFT JOIN #song AS s ON s.BandId = b.BandId  -- left join includes 0's
GROUP BY b.BandId ,
         b.BandName
HAVING   COUNT(s.SongId) < 3;  -- filters to bands with less than 3 songs

DROP TABLE #band;
DROP TABLE #song;
```

Produces:

```
BandId      BandName   Songs
----------- ---------- -----------
4           Poppers    0
2           Rappers    2
3           Ravers     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a `left join`:

```
select b.name, count(s.bandid) as NUMBER_OF_SONGS
from bands b left join
     songs s
     on b.bandid = s.bandid  -- or whatever your join conditions are
group by b.name
having count(s.bandid) < 3;
```